# why object variable property did not work in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, object

I have a utility function which pass parameters 'name page callback'  to the function. Why not work as i tried so many times?

PLUS: seems 'query.tag_id = name' work for me but why query[name] = name did not work so that i can pass whatever name i like;That's, i want to pass the variable /name/ as the property name so that i can use whatever name i like. For example, i can find posts by user_id when i pass user_id variable as the name value. Also i can find posts by its tag_id when i pass tag_id variable as the name value so it's much more flexible than when i use 'query.user_id = name' to do it ,where the name can only be user_id variable or value

NO LIBRARY USED EXCEPT EXPRESS AND NODEJS WITH CONNECT-FLESH, MONGOOSE ETC.

// post_proxy/post.js

```
"use strict";
let moment = require('moment'),
    Post = require('../models/Post'),
    User = require('../models/User'),
    Comment = require('../models/Comment'),
    postProxy = require('../db_proxy/post'),
    tagProxy = require('../db_proxy/tag');
module.exports = {
       getTen:  (name,page,callback)=>{

                var query = {};
                //name = query;
                if(name){

                    query[name] = name;
                    console.log('query[name] is'+ Object.keys(query));

                }
                Post.count(query, ( err, count)=>{

                    if (err) {
                            return callback(err);
                    }else{
                            console.log( `Number of posts: ${count} . query is ${query}` );

                            Post.find(query).skip((page-1)*10).limit(10).sort({created_at: -1}).exec((err,posts)=>{
                                    if (err) {
                                        return callback(err);
                                    }
                                    console.log('Posts inthe getTen function is: '+posts);
                                    const modifiedPosts = posts.map(post=>{
                                        return post.processPost(post);
                                    });

                                    console.log('modifiedPosts: '+modifiedPosts);
                                    callback(null, modifiedPosts, count);//provide the params(caluated values),and what to do? you need to figure it out yourself


                            });  
                    }

                });  
}
```

//  controller/post.js:

```
"use strict";
let moment = require('moment'),
    Post = require('../models/Post'),
    User = require('../models/User'),
    Comment = require('../models/Comment'),
    postProxy = require('../db_proxy/post'),
    tagProxy = require('../db_proxy/tag');

    module.exports = {
         getTagsPost: (req,res)=>{
                    const tag_id = req.params.tag_id;
                    const page = req.query.p ? parseInt(req.query.p) : 1;
                    //let loginedUser;
                    console.log('entering into the tagpost');


                    postProxy.getTen(tag_id, page, (err, posts, count)=> {
                        if (err) {
                        console.log('some error with getting the 10 posts:'+ err);
                        //next(err);
                        posts = [];
                        } 
                        // if(req.user){
                        //     loginedUser = req.user.processUser(req.user);
                        // }
                        //userProxy.getUserById(user_id, theuser=>{
                        console.log('tag posts for'+ tag_id +posts);

                        res.render('post/tagPosts', {
                                title: 'specific tag page',
                                user: req.user ? req.user.processUser(req.user) : req.user,
                                //postUser: req.user ? (req.user._id == user_id ? loginedUser : theuser) : theuser,
                                posts: posts,
                                page: page,
                                isFirstPage: (page - 1) == 0,
                                isLastPage: ((page - 1) * 10 + posts.length) == count,
                                messages: {
                                    error: req.flash('error'),
                                    success: req.flash('success'),
                                    info: req.flash('info'),
                                }, // get the user out of session and pass to template
                        }); 


                    });            

         },
         ...
    }
```

//route:

```
router.get('/tag/:tag_id', post.getTagsPost);
```

UPDATE:
Did not find an answer so i change it to the following and solve the problems:

```
        getTen:  (name,tag_id,user_id,page,callback)=>{

                var query = {};
                if(name){
                    if(user_id){         
                        query.user_id = name;
                    }else{
                        query.tag_id = name;

                    }
                    console.log('query[name] is'+ Object.keys(query));
                }
                ...
}
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean in this case? Do you get an error in the console, or...?

Comment: the console shows me: query[name] is57c2c29bfcf033970f2bbecf
Number of posts: 0 . query is [object Object]

Comment: And what did you expect it to show? (And where is "Number of posts: 0" coming from? Nothing in the code shown should output that.) When you say `query[name] = name`, you create a property with both the name and value being the same. That is, if `name` is `"abc"` then you are creating `{ abc : "abc" }`.

Comment: but what if name is a variable. I've added all the code above right now

Comment: @Frank Adding code doesn't answer the question, however.  What are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry, i want to pass the variable name as the property name so that i can use whatever name i like. For example, i can find post by user_id when i pass user_id variable as the name value. Also i can find posts by its tag_id when i pass tag_id variable as the name value so it's much more flexible than when i use 'query.user_id = name' to do it

Comment: @Frank And the problems you are experiencing, specifically, are?

Comment: @Frank This will be my last attempt: State your actions leading up to your problem, what you expect, and what you're getting instead.  It is not currently clear from your question, even edits in mind, where the problem is; you have to remember that we know nothing about your situation, such as what libraries you may be using, and how they operate.

Comment: thanks for your responding. really appreciated. as to what i expect,it's in the plus section above,i do not know what your misunderstanding is.

Comment: @Frank It is not in the 'plus section' above.  When you are ready to look at your question from an outside perspective, and re-write it to be more clear, let me know.

Comment: @Daedalus, have a check and feel free to let me know anything you want,thanks

Comment: @Frank I already have.  I requested libraries.  The method you added looks like it comes from angularjs, or even angular 2.0.  However, given you haven't added any other pertinent details, my questions stand.  Alert me _only_ when all details that are missing, have been added.  As it stands, I see usage of several methods/functions which are not present in standard NodeJS.

Comment: @Daedalus, it's the backend code of nodejs, no other libraries used except for express. and ignore 'req.user.processUser', which is  my own implementation in the user model to process some data

Comment: seems that i pass a variable /name/ which then place it with another variable  /tag_id/ so that query[name] is not equal to query.tag_id. Finally query[name] is equal to query.c (c is tag_id's value).Thanks for your respond and you can post your answer below and i will choose yours as the best answer,thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Did not find an answer so i change it to the following and solve the problems:

```
        getTen:  (name,tag_id,user_id,page,callback)=>{

                var query = {};
                if(name){
                    if(user_id){         
                        query.user_id = name;
                    }else{
                        query.tag_id = name;

                    }
                    console.log('query[name] is'+ Object.keys(query));
                }
                ...
}
```